# Why does sulfur exist as octasulfur?

Tags: periodic-table, periodic-trends

Sulfur belongs to the same group as oxygen. Then why oxygen exists as an $\ce{O2}$ molecule while sulfur exists as $\ce{S8}$ molecule? What's the chemistry behind this?